# ¿tengo un formulario en c# y cuando lo ejecuto no me muestra activa la x de cerrar?

Tags: c#, windows-forms

¿como hago para activar la x de cerrar en dicho formulario ya que no logro identificar cual es la propiedad del formulario que lo hace?

[image: así se esta viendo mi formulario]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una vez te posiciones en tu formulario dentro de las propiedades puede intentar modificar esta propiedad:

[image: Propiedades del formulario]

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda

Comment: Un gusto poder ayudarte.